# Calculate value depending on multiple conditions

Tags: tableau-api

[image]I have Grp_ids feild which i need to assign "Pass" or "Fail" based on the results of measure_ids

For example : If one of the measure_ids in the group is failed, i want the whole group to be failed.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet and what was the result?  Will you be using the GRP_RESULT at any other level of dimension or just the GRP_IDS?

Comment: It will be just the Grp-ids

Comment: Hint: Try LOD (with multiple keys) and IF ELSE condition together in a calculated field.

Comment: could you please explain it further?

Comment: Official document on Level of detail (LOD): https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm. Also please let us know what you have tried and how you have approached the problem. For help on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Define Grp_Result as `MIN([Measure_Results] = "Pass")`

That will be True if Measure_Results = "Pass" for every data row for your selected dimensions (Grp_Ids and Measure_is in your example). If you can have null values in your Measure_Results column and if you want to treat those nulls as a Fail, then would use instead `MIN(IFNULL([Measure_Results] = "Pass"), False)`

This works because Tableau treats True as greater than False. So MAX() holds if  is satisfied for EVERY data row, and MAX() holds if  is satisfied for ANY data row.

You can simplify a bit further by using boolean values in place of strings to begin with to represent whether a record passed or failed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick -

```
IIF({ FIXED [Grp_ids]: SUM(IIF([Measure_Results] = 'Pass',0,1)) }>0,'Fail','Pass')
```

Sum the failures by GRP_ID. If the sum is greater than 0 (GRP_ID contains a Fail) then Fail the entire GRP_ID.